# Can I use a factor score as dependent variable, and if so, what model should I use?

Tags: regression, factor-analysis

I'm doing a survey-based research design and I have EFA factor score for variables I want to use as both dependent variables and independent variables. I've read on some other forum saying that one CANNOT use a factor score as a dependent variable. Is that the case? Or it really depends on how established the theory is regarding my factor analysis?

If I can use factor score as DV, what regression model should I  use?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: what is your primary data and stat purpose of research.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My data is from survey answers (WVS) and the purpose of research is to determine the possible correlation between different kinds of attitudes.

Comment: If you are intersted in regression, why you should compute factor scores.

Comment: Because the factor analysis is just to determine the latent variables I'm going to test in the regression analysis.

Comment: what is your dependent variable for a regression analysis

Comment: what are your latent variables and dependent variable (nominal or continuous).

Comment: It sounds a bit as though you are trying to re-invent structural equation modelling. Do you want to do some background reading and then ask a new question?

Comment: You can take a look here: (pdf) for a discussion on using factors scores in regression (see in particular Table 1, 3rd column, for the case of independent variable observed, dependent variable factor scores)